# What's the meaning of ::std::vector

Tags: c++, vector

I just saw in some DLib code, in a .cpp file a thing like that:

```
#include <stdio>

namespace {

  using namespace std;

  void foo() {
    ::std::vector<int> my_vector;
  }
}
```

Is there a reason we specify `::std::` in front of our `vector` we imported from `std` already ?

Comment: IMO these are bad dupes, AFAICT OP is asking whats the point of having *both* `using namespace std;` *and* `::std::`

Comment: Even if you `use namespace std`, you might shadow the names locally. The double colon forces access to the namespace.

Comment: from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice - this explictly picks vector from std rather than any other namespace that might be floating around